# Property not getting overridden in CSS file

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a common class for my button object and override just some properties in another class, e.g. `.shopping_cart_btn`.

For some reason my second class is not overriding certain properties in my first class. As an experiment I tried writing both classes with just one background-color property and overriding works fine according to the order in which the classes are defined in the CSS. But for some reason the class I have written does not work. Can someone help me with this?

```css
.button {
  display: block;
  background-color: #ffec64;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffec64), color-stop(1, #ffab23));
  color: #333333;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #ffee66;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ffaa22;
  margin: auto;
}

.button:hover {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffab23), color-stop(1, #ffec64));
  background-color: #ffab23;
}

.button:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<button class='button shopping_cart_btn' id="shoppingCart-btn">Shopping Cart</button>
```

Comment: You only have one class mentioned in your CSS.

Comment: Try providing a [mcve]. Demonstrate the problem using as few different properties as possible. Get rid of the rulesets that use pseudo-classes (unless you need them to demonstrate the problem). Click the snippet button in the question editor's toolbar so you can provide a live demo.

Comment: What are the 'certain properties' you're trying to override?

Comment: order of priority in CSS; inline vs  most specific in external, also there is an `important` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to override for me, using this as an example:

```css
.button {
  display: block;
  background-color: #ffec64;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffec64), color-stop(1, #ffab23));
  color: #333333;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #ffee66;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ffaa22;
  margin: auto;
}

.button:hover {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffab23), color-stop(1, #ffec64));
  background-color: #ffab23;
}

.button:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}

.shopping_cart_btn {
  color: #fff;
  background: green;
}

.shopping_cart_btn:hover {
  background: blue;
}

.shopping_cart_btn:active {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<button class='button shopping_cart_btn' id="shoppingCart-btn">Shopping Cart</button>

<button class='button'>Regular button</button>
```

If the issue was specifically the `background-color`, then `background` will supersede all previous `background-color`, `background-image`, etc. specifications. It's basically a shorthand, but a reset as well.

Comment: Oh yes, that worked! Trying to figure out what is different. Thank you very much for the quick response.

Comment: Looks like background takes precedence over background-color?

Comment: Background will supersede all previous background-color, background-image, etc. specifications. It's basically a shorthand, but a reset as well.